# CSS menu - position left or right automatically?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, themes

I'm trying to figure out how to make my CSS menu drop down and fly out (on hover) to the right on the left parents, and automatically fly out to the left for the right parents.  This is done neatly on the theme here:
http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=sentient 
I'm trying to copy the mini-cart style to my other wootheme.  If you add something to the cart and hover over the mini-cart you can see.
My menu styling is set to always go right, and I can't figure out where to adapt it.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: *I can't figure out* is not enough... You have to actually try something, and show us where you got stuck

Comment: Try adding the code you've written so far to a http://jsfiddle.net/ editor and posting the link with a description of what isn't working. Then people will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the position of the dropdown menu with javascript and apply a style conditionally (this won't work exactly but this is the idea):

jQuery

```
    $('.dropdown-parent').hover( function(){ 
      //If to left of center of screen
      $(this).children('.dropdown').css('dropdown-right');
      $(this).children('.dropdown').css('right', $(this).width());

      //Else if to right of screen
      $(this).children('.dropdown').css('dropdown-left');
      $(this).children('.dropdown').css('left', $(this).width());
    }, function(){ 
      $(this).hide();
    } )
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-parent {
  position:relative;
}      
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm going to try this.

Answer (score -1):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avczfojt/) :**Pure CSS**

Place the `ul` of the drop down inside the `li` of the navigation bar list. Normally the nested `ul` appears right below the `li`. Apply `position:absolute;` for the `ul`, adjust it `width` and if you need, adjust the `margin-left` of the `ul`.